# Requesting the user password

Tags: android, keyguard, keyguardlock

I have an app, that features a screen which should be protected by for example `KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent`. This api however, is only available on 21+, I've tried using the `KeyguardManager.newKeyguardLock` and setting `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`, but that does not seem to work at all, how do I get it to work on older devices?